# Is the sentence “While i was traveling i had seen beautiful buildings.” ungrammatical?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Is the sentence “While i was traveling i had seen beautiful buildings.” ungrammatical?

I think this sentence is grammatical using past perfect to describe multiple events in past
 but the answer says ‘while i was traveling I saw beautiful buildings’ is correct.

Why the sentence ‘while i was traveling i had seen beautiful buildings’ is incorrect?

Comment: The problem is that without further context, the past perfect sets *I had seen beautiful buildings* as an event that happened before *I was traveling*, contradicting the word *while*. With further context, the sentence could be correct. For example, *While I was traveling, I had seen some beautiful buildings, but compared with the Palace of the Dictator, they all seemed like crude mud hovels.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't incorrect (except that 'I' should always be in upper case). As a sentence on its own, it's probably better with 'saw', but you could say something like "While I was travelling I had seen some beautiful buildings, but the new art gallery in my home town was as fine as any of them".

Comment: It is not correct because "while" implies doing something at the same time in both clauses of the sentence.  "Had been" implies that the buildings were seen before they were travelling.

Comment: If "while I was traveling" means "back when I was traveling", then "had seen" works as having happened at the same time as traveling.

Comment: @Karlomanio I disagree. "I had seen some beautiful buildings while I was travelling" works, so why not the other way round?

Comment: That's not correct either for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT grammatical.

The correct wording should be

> While I was travelling, I saw beautiful buildings.

This is because the use of "while" implies doing something at the same time in both clauses of the sentence. "Had been" implies that the buildings were seen before they were travelling.

Please refer to this site for [uses of the past perfect](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/past-perfect-tense-examples.html).